# Right click option to copy file name (or directory name)

Tags: nautilus, menu

I'm trying to find a way to have the right click option to copy file name (or directory name).

I'm use nautilus scripts but I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Thank you. The script works, but it ads two new lines at the end. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Well, now there's only one new line at the end. I'm on debian XFCE and installed Nautilus (3.4.2) as an extra file manager.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` then `filepath=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` then `name=${filepath##*/}` then `name=${name%` then `}` then `printf %s "$name" | xclip -selection clipboard` (so the second closing brace is on a separate line)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it still ads a line break at the end

Comment: Well, that definitely has to do with your setup because I used the last version for an entire day and it worked as expected on my system (no trailing newlines). Anyway, the proper way to do this would be with `python` (or, even better, `C` - but I don't know `C`) - however I don't have the time to look into this right now...

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal window.
cd "Directory" (without the quotes) -- hit the enter key.
ls (then hit "Enter" Key)

After the list is returned in the window, highlight and copy the list of returned files, then copy them to a doc or spreadsheet.

Example 1:
cd Documents (followed by Enter key)
ls (followed by Enter key)

Copy the generated list of files in the Documents directory/folder and paste into spreadsheet, or simply save them into a text file.

Comment: Where does this provide a solution to the question, though?